# Unable to pass props from the parent to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have navigation screens in my App.js with one screen rendering custom header as:

```
const DailyStack = createStackNavigator({
  Dashboard,
  SalesDashboard: {
    screen : SalesDashboard,
    navigationOptions:{
      header: null,
    }
  },
  StackNavSecond : {
    screen: StackNavSecond, 
      navigationOptions : {
        header : <CustomHeader />,

      }
  },....
```

Then in my `CustomHeader.js` file, I have some state data:

```
class CustomHeader extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      title:'Regions',
      subtitle:'',
      oem: ''
    }
  }

 async componentDidMount(){

   let car_brand = await AsyncStorage.getItem('brand_name');
   let main_oem = await AsyncStorage.getItem('oem_name');

   await this.setState({
             oem: main_oem,
             subtitle: car_brand,
   });

   console.log(this.state.oem)
  }



render() {
    console.log(this.state.title)
   const {title, subtitle, oem} = this.state;
    return (
             <View>  
               <CustomDropdown title={title} subtitle={subtitle} oem={oem} /> 
             </View>
          )
     }
}

export default withNavigation(CustomHeader);
```

The prop `title` is not getting passed to its child component which is getting rendered further in two more screens.

The code for `CustomDropdown.js` is:

```
    class CustomDropdown extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)

            this.state = {
                 title: '',
                 oem: '',
                 subtitle:''
            };
        }

        componentDidMount(){
           this.setState({
             title:this.props.title,
             subtitle: this.props.subtitle,
             oem: this.props.oem, 
           });
           console.log(this.state.title, this.state.oem, this.state.subtitle)
        }

        render() {
             return (
                <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                  .........  
                </View>
            )
        }
    }


export default withNavigation(CustomDropdown);
```

When I console `this.state.title`, it prints but no value for `subtitle` and `oem`. I even tried putting console statement inside the `callback()` of `this.setState()` but still, no props gets print for oem and subtitle.

Please help to resolve this.

Comment: Try `console.log(props)` in the constructor of `CustomDropdown` and see what's being passed down.

Comment: And you're not sending any `oem` and `subtitle`, they are left empty, check your state object in `CustomHeader`

Comment: I am setting their values after component being mounted. I also tried directly setting the values oem: this.props.oem, but it also doesn't work

Comment: You are right about doing the logging in the `callback` of `this.setState()`. And you are passing empty strings down the props please check once again in the `CustomHeader`'s state object
`this.state = {
      title:'Regions',
      subtitle:'',
      oem: ''
    }`
They are empty

Comment: @PhaniRithvij I am sorry for my mistake. I forgot to add major code that I am using to update value of state in componentDidMount(). I am using asyncstorage to set the empty state values then passing it to customDropdown, and that's not working. I have edited the code. Kindly see to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withNavigation` when you do not want to deliver components. But your code is deeply nested.

If you want to use it like this, you can change the code like this.

**CustomHeader.js**

```js
class CustomHeader extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      title:'Regions',
      subtitle:'',
      oem: ''
    }
  }

 async componentDidMount(){

   let car_brand = await AsyncStorage.getItem('brand_name');
   let main_oem = await AsyncStorage.getItem('oem_name');

   this.setState({
             oem: main_oem,
             subtitle: car_brand,
   });

   console.log(this.state.oem)
  }


render() {
    console.log(this.state.title)
   const {title, subtitle, oem} = this.state;
    return (
             <View>  
               <CustomDropdown title={title} subtitle={subtitle} oem={oem} /> 
             </View>
          )
     }
}

export default withNavigation(CustomHeader);
```

**CustomDropdown.js**

```js
    class CustomDropdown extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                 title: props.title,
                 oem: props.oem,
                 subtitle: props.subtitle
            };
        }

        componentDidMount(){
           console.log(this.state.title, this.state.oem, this.state.subtitle)
        }

        render() {
             return (
                <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                  .........  
                </View>
            )
        }
    }


export default CustomDropdown;
```

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake. I forgot to add major code that I am using to update value of state in componentDidMount(). I am using asyncstorage to set the empty state values then passing it to customDropdown, and that's not working. I have edited the code. Kindly see to it.

Comment: You can add the items you need. Your answer has been modified.

Comment: values are still empty.

Comment: How is it possible to pass 'props.oem' instead of 'this.props.oem' in class based components?

Comment: Can you see the value 'this.state.oem' in the console log?

Comment: @bubble-cord Study the difference between this and the constructor.